# How can I store the alphabet letters in a array and Display it? C#

Tags: c#, loops

I have to use `for(char letter='A';letter<='Z'....)`. When I do it using the following code the alphabet repeats about 12 times.

```
char[] alphabet = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
{
    for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
    {
        alphabet[i] = letter;
        Console.WriteLine(alphabet[i]);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your code loops through all array indexes, then assignes each array element all letters one after another. You probaly wanted to assign only one letter, so remove the inner loop and replace it by alphabet[i] = (char)('A' + i);

Comment: How can I use a display method to display the elements on the array?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have 2 loops, when you only need one and/or and index

```
var alphabet = new char[26];
var i = 0;

for (var letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
    alphabet[i++] = letter;

foreach (var c in alphabet)
    Console.WriteLine(c);

// or index

var alphabet = new char[26];
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    alphabet[i] = (char)(i + 'A');

foreach (var c in alphabet)
    Console.WriteLine(c);


// or a linq solution

var chars = Enumerable.Range('A', 26)
                    .Select(x => (char)x)
                    .ToArray();

foreach (var c in chars)
    Console.WriteLine(c);
```

**Or as provided by [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio)**

> I think alphabet will never change, so you can hardcode it

```
var ary = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
```

Comment: I think alphabet will never change, so you can hardcode it: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()`

Comment: How can I use a display method to display the elements on the array? –

Comment: @brown, i dont understand , they are being displayed, try  `Console.WriteLine(Join("",chars))`